# Transaction, Operations, and Payments

Tags: transactions, horizon, operations

I am currently trying to get the `memo` and `amount` of a transaction, but am confused over the differences between a `transaction`, an `operation`, and a `payment`.

From my understanding, a `transaction` contains multiple `operations`, one of which is a `payment`.

However, when querying with `horizon.stellar.org`, which of the following should I be using to get both `memo` and `amount`?

`server.transactions().forAccount(accountId).call()...`
`server.operations().forAccount(accountId).call()...`
`server.payments().forAccount(accountId).call()...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memo can be seen on the transaction. e.g.

```
    "memo_type": "text",
    "memo": "chp_290",
```

You can then decode the `envelope_xdr` value to drill down on the details of the operations within the transaction. Or you can make a subsequent call to the payments by transaction endpoint, where the asset and amount can be seen. e.g.

```
    "type": "payment",
    "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
    "asset_code": "TEST",
    "asset_issuer": "GDNFUWF2EO4OWXYLI4TDEH4DXUCN6PB24R6XQW4VATORK6WGMHGRXJVB",
    "amount": "1000000.0000000"
```

The payment endpoint is an alias for a filtered operations call, where only `create_account` and `payment` operations are included.